# Using Contains Method to separate comma delimited string of numbers

Tags: c#, methods, contains

I have an IF statement as follows:

```
        if (snumber == "9999-999-9999" && cnumber == "999")
        {
            // 30 Day Trial Demo Key
            return "Good";
        }
```

There's a serial number linked to one or multiple cnumbers.  In some cases I have a list of 5-20 cnumbers seperated by commas, but that method will not work for what I'm doing. I believe I need to use the Contains method to let the program know any one of those values will work for that serial number.  Any insight or work around?

Thanks

C#

Answer (score 1):

You could split your list of `cnumbers` by comma and iterate the array checking each `cnumber` against your value.

```
if(snumber == "9999-999-9999")
{  
    var cnumbers = listOfCnumbers.Split(',');
    foreach(var cnumber in cnumbers)
    {
        if(cnumber == "999")
        {
             return "Good";
        }
    }
}
```

Might want to replace the hardcoded strings with variables though